# Proving that $\sin x \cos x =\dfrac{1}{2} \sin 2x$ by using the series definition of $\sin x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

As we know, we can define that:

$$\sin x= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!},\quad x \in \boldsymbol{R}$$
and also

$$\cos x= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!},\quad x \in \boldsymbol{R}$$

Furthermore, we know this equation is true:

$$\sin x \cos x =\dfrac{1}{2} \sin 2x \tag{1}$$

I have tried to prove this as follows: using the Cauchy product,

\begin{eqnarray}
\sin x \cos x& =&\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)
\\&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^i\dfrac{x^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}(-1)^{n-i}\dfrac{x^{2n-2i}}{(2n-2i)!}\right)\\
&=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^n \dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2i+1)!(2n-2i)!}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n x^{2n+1}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\dfrac{1}{(2i+1)!(2n-2i)!}\right)
\end{eqnarray}

But the right side of equation (1) is $\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \dfrac{2^{2n+1} x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $.
It's so weird! I don't know how to make them equal!

Comment: use $e^{2\pi i\phi}=\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi)$ instead.

Comment: You are doing well. You just have to figure out why that sum equals $2^{2n}/(2n+1)!$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint : $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{(2i+1)!(2n-2i)!}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)!}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{2n+1\choose 2i+1}$$

Comment: thank you very much! i'll try .